# Installing perl DBD::mysql fails on Mac Sierra with mysql brew install

Tags: perl, macos-sierra, cpanm, dbd-mysql

Trying to install `DBD::mysql` on my Mac Sierra computer running mysql v 5.7.17. Getting the following error when trying to install with `cpanm install DBD::mysql`:

`Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Can't link/include C library 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting.`

Other solutions I have found so far don't address this issue with Sierra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass `libs` and `cflags` arg to help `Makefile.PL` find the libaries on the machine (in my case the openssl libraries were installed with homebrew):

`cpanm  --configure-args="--libs='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/lib' --cflags='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/include/mysql'" DBD::mysql`

Comment: Typo: the first "oenssl" should be "openssl".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`cpanm --configure-args="--libs='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto' --cflags='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/include/mysql'" DBD::mysql`